# What is the easiest way to create and publish podcasts?

Tags: windows, macos, audio-recording, podcasts

I am a software engineer, and unfortunately people know it.  So I get those inevitable computer questions.  This time it is a relatively simple one I think, but one for which I have no experience.

**How can I create and publish podcasts?**

Any solution should be first and foremost easy for a novice computer user to go from start to finish without additional help.  If software is required, it should be reasonably priced or free.

**Edit**: The user has access to both Windows and OSX.

Comment: Please specify your operating system: Windows? OS X?

Comment: They have access to both Windows and OSX.

Answer (score 2):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is the canonical answer for free audio software.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of pod producing software [here](http://www.podcast.de/software/podproducer/) (german, but the links will work for you, I think)

Comment: So this is not so much a recommendation as a canned search.  Don't you have an opinion?

Comment: I think these programs should be tried and then chosen according to personal preferences. GarageBand, PodcastMaker (both Mac) or Audacity are all good pieces of software. It really depends on your level of expertise and personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it myself, but know of people having success with [PodcastMaker](http://www.lemonzdream.com/podcastmaker/) for the Mac.